# Creating report with Aspose.Word without losing formatting

Tags: c#, report, aspose, aspose.words

I am using `Aspose.Words` to create reports from a template file (`.docx` filetype).

After using `Aspose.Words` to modify the template file and saving it into a new file, the formatting of the template file were lost (such as **bold** text, [image] *comments*, etc).

I have tried:

```
Aspose.Words.Document doc = new Document(inputStream);
var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
doc.Save(outputStream, SaveFormat.docx);
```

What I did not expect is that outputStream is much less bytes than inputStream although I have yet to make any modification on `doc`. It may the reason why the report file lose their formatting.

What should I try now?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the problem is because the current version of `Aspose.Words` I'm using does not support `docx` filetype. But it still can read text of a `.docx` file, and only text(without any associated formatting).